# Obtener filas sin tener que hacer múltiples consultas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un sistema de comentarios donde tengo una tabla que contiene comentarios guardados.

Necesito obtener cada comentario de la tabla con una sola consulta con arrays asociativos en vez de consultar la tabla cada vez que necesito obtener el siguiente comentario.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<?
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($conexion,'ADLG');

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios') or die('Error al consultar: ' . mysql_error());
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$numeroComents = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($resultado AND $numeroComents > 0)
    for($i=0; $i < $numeroComents; $i++){
        //Se genera una consulta cada vez que se necesita obtener el siguiente comentario
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE ID='.($i+1).'') or die('Error al consultar: ' . mysql_error());
        $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        echo '<div class="comentario">',$r['user']," '",$r['ID'],"'<br />", $r['message'],'<div><br />';
    }
?>
```

### Esctructura de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por qué el  where en la segunda consulta y no en la primera ?, por que lo igualas a un contador de un for ? quizá si nos dijera que obtiene con su forma de trabajar y que es lo que desea obtener. sería mucho mejor.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la estructura de la tabla? Como dice el compañero, haces la misma consulta 2 veces.

Comment: Hago una primera consulta para mysqli_num_rows devuelva el numero de filas(comentarios)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,'ADLG');

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM comentarios') or die('Error al consultar: ' . mysql_error());
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo '<div class="comentario">',$r['user']," '",$r['ID'],"'<br />", $r['message'],'<div><br />';
}

?>
```

Con este código se recorren las filas obtenidas en una única consulta sin tener que realizar una segunda consulta

Comment: ¿Algo asi como un bucle for-each?, ¿como se podría implementar un bucle for-each con esa misma función?

Comment: Estás mezclando `mysql` y `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

Con los datos que has puesto, solo te faltaría hacer un sistema de paginación, para los comentarios, y simplemente con la primera consulta tendrías solucionado tu problema.

Comment: Creo que esto pudo ser añadido como comentario y no  como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
// MySQLi por Procedimiento

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database_name";

// Crear Conexión
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Revisar Conexión
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  echo "Error de conexión MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Preguntar si existen comentarios
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `comentarios`");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $comments = 0; // Iniciar Contador
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $comments++; // cantidad de comentarios
  }
  $show_comments = TRUE;
}else {
  $show_comments = FALSE;
}   
mysqli_close($conn);


if($show_comments == FALSE){
  echo 'Esta publicación no posee comentarios';
} else { 
// Ya sabemos que tiene comentarios. $comments servirá para el paginador si lo quieres agregar dividiendo en cuantos comentarios se mostrará por página

  if(!isset($_GET['list']) || empty($_GET['list']) || preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $_GET['list'])){ 
    $url_list = (1); 
  }else{ 
    $url_list = $_GET['list']; 
  }
  $list_count = 15; // Ó cuantos quieras mostrar
  $list_to = $url_list * $list_count; 
  $list_from = $list_to - $list_count;
  if($list_from <= 0){ 
    $limit = '0'.','.$list_count;
  }else{ 
    $limit = $list_from.','.$list_count; 
  }

  $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `comentarios` LIMIT $limit ORDER `id` DESC ");
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<div class="comentario">',$row['user']," '",$row['ID'],"'<br />", $row['message'],'<div><br />';    
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);

}
```